How do I do basic date grouping operations in Google Sheets?
I have data that looks like this (sample):



Col A
Col B
Col C




Value 1
Value 2
1/4/24 4:15 pm


Value 3
Value 4
1/4/24 6:30 pm


Value 5
Value 6
1/5/24 2:30 pm


Value 7
Value 8
1/5/24 3:30 pm


Value 9
Value 10
1/5/24 5:30 pm



I'm trying to do something that, in proper SQL, should be pretty straightforward: "for each date Col C, not date/time, in the table, find the number of hours including decimal hours elapsed between the earliest and latest event on that date." The values in Col A and Col B are not relevant.
Net result is I want this to come back, or something similar (comment just for readability here):



Date
Hours
Comment




1/4/24
2.25
6:30pm - 4:15pm


1/5/24
3
5:30pm - 2:30pm, because 3:30pm isn't a min or max



In SQL, I'd guess the query would be like this, with some pseudocode:
SELECT
   number_of_hours(MAX(col_c) - MIN(col_c))
FROM
   my_table
GROUP BY
   DATE(col_c)

I can't figure out how to do this in Google Sheets. Given I've thought of the problem more like a database problem than something you'd do in a spreadsheet, I tried the QUERY function but everything I do ends up with an invalid query. I'm thinking Google Sheets doesn't allow you to extract the date portion of a date/time and aggregate it.
Things I've tried but failed:

=query(A:C, "SELECT A, B, C, " & TEXT(C, "yyyy-mm-dd"), 1): Formula parse error
=query(A:C, "SELECT A, B, C, " & DATE(C), 1): Formula parse error
=query(A:C, "SELECT C, COUNT(B) GROUP BY " & DATE(C), 1): Formula parse error
=query(A:C, "SELECT C, COUNT(B) GROUP BY DATE(C)", 1): Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 33
=query(A:C, "SELECT C, DATE '" & YEAR(C) & "-" & (MONTH(C) + 1) & "-" & DAY(C) & "'", 1): Formula parse error
=query(A:C, "SELECT C, " & DATEVALUE(YEAR(C) & "-" & (MONTH(C) + 1) & "-" & DAY(C)), 1): Formula parse error
=query(A:C, "SELECT C, DATE(YEAR(C), MONTH(C), DAY(C))", 1): Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 15

So how can I go about doing this?

You can use:
=SORT(LET(
   c,TOCOL(C2:C,1),
   d,TEXT(c,"m/d/yy"),
   MAP(UNIQUE(d),LAMBDA(u,LET(
    f,FILTER(c,d=u)*24,
    {u,MAX(f)-MIN(f)}))))) 


That is amazing, nothing I would have ever come close to thinking of, and it works. Thanks!

There are some issues, when dealing with spreadsheet dates and Google's query dates:

Arithmetic operations like difference is not supported for date objects in query. This makes it hard to calculate actual differences.

Google query's date object's epoch is January 1, 1970, while the starting date on spreadsheet is 30 Dec 1899. The difference is 25569 days

Query represents date as milliseconds from epoch, while sheets represents it as days from 30 Dec 1899.


We overcome these by changing sheet dates TO PURE NUMBERs(days) and then converting it to milliseconds from epoch(-25569) and then using query on it:
=LET(
  days2ms,24*60*60*1000,
  diff, "(max(Col1)-min(Col1))/"&days2ms,
  QUERY(
    ARRAYFORMULA((TO_PURE_NUMBER(C1:C5)-25569)*days2ms),
    "Select 
      toDate(Col1),
      "&diff&" 
     group by toDate(Col1) 
     format "&diff&" 'h.m'"))

Output:



toDate()
quotient(difference(max min )86400000())




1/4/2024
2.15


1/5/2024
3.0




If you are willing to nest QUERYs then you can achieve the desired result in a slightly more SQL-like manner:
=query(query(A:C,
"select toDate(C),hour(C)+(minute(C)/60) where C is not null",1),
"select Col1,max(Col2)-min(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Date',max(Col2)-min(Col2) 'Hours'",1)

